# ios - AVFoundation custom compositor not working in ios 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, opengl-es-2.0

I've been working on a project using `AVFoundation` and on that I've been trying to use the AVMutableVideoComposition's customVideoCompositorClass. Everything works fine in ios 9.x and above.

But when I run the same project in an ios 8.3 device (iPhone 5s), only audio plays and video player remains black for the entire composition playing.

Then I tried to run the [`AVCustomEdit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCustomEdit/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code provided by apple which also uses customVideoCompositorClass for video frame processing (Uses `opengl es 2.0`). Same black thing also happened there too. In this project for `texture` generation from `CVPixelBufferRef` it uses `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` and `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef`. Not sure it causes the black issue?

I would be very happy if anyone can suggest me some pointers regarding this. Thanks in advance.